# Php multiple dropdown list, using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, search

I am trying to make a live search code in PHP with 3 drop down box have the values from db so my users can select what contents they want to search for instead of displaying in DataTable below. I can link them now by script and searching then the first dropdownbox working well, but I have no Ideas to do a search function from the second. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3gmn.jpg)

It is my script code:

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#fetchal").on('change',function(){
    var value_fetchal = $(this).val();
    $.ajax(
    {
        url:'search.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:'request_fetchal='+value_fetchal,
        beforeSend:function()
        {
            $("#table-container").html("Working on...");
        },
        success:function(data)
        {
            $("#table-container").html(data);
            var len = response.length;
            $("#search_MONTH").empty();
            for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                var month = response[i]['search_MONTH'];
                $("#search_MONTH").append("<option value='"+month+"'>"+month+"</option>");
            }
            $("#search_YEAR").empty();
            for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                var year = response[i]['search_YEAR'];
                $("#search_YEAR").append("<option value='"+year+"'>"+year+"</option>");
            }
        },
    });
});
});
```

It is my search.php code:

```
if ($_POST['request_fetchal']) {
$request1 = $_POST['request_fetchal'];
$request_year = year;
$request_month = month;
require_once("includes/connection.php");
//CAU LENH SQL
$sql5= "SELECT * from form where center ='$request1' and createdate(year) = 'year' and createdate(month)= 'month'  order by id ";
$result5 = $conn->query($sql5);
echo '<table-border="1">';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th width="3%">審閲</th>';
echo '<th width="5%">已列印</th>';
echo '<th width="3%">選擇</th>';
echo '<th width="3%">流水編號</th>';
echo '<th width="3%">賬號</th>';
echo '<th width="3%">部門代碼</th>';
echo '<th width="5%">利潤中心</th>';
echo '<th width="10%">發生日</th>';
echo '<th width="15%">項目</th>';
echo '<th width="15%">科目</th>';
echo '<th width="5%">支出金額</th>';
echo '<th width="5%">有無單據</th>';
echo '<th width="5%">領收款人</th>';
echo '<th width="5%">應扣款人</th>'; 
echo '<th width="10%">扣款説明</th>';     
echo '<th width="20%">備註(無單據說明)</th>';
while ($output = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result5)) {
echo '<tr>';
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='mycheckbox2[]' value='" .$output['id']. "'>".$output['checked']."</td>";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='mycheckbox[]' value='" .$output['id']. "'>".$output['printed']."</td>";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='" .$output['id']. "'></td>";
echo '<td>'.$output['id'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$output['username'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$output['department'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$output['center'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$output['createdate'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$output['object'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$output['subject'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$output['total_money'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$output['receipt'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$output['name_receive'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$output['name_koukuanren'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$output['koukuanshuoming'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$output['note'].'</td>';
};
echo '</table>';
```

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp checkout it

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. Please use `prepared statements` instead of embedding user supplied data directly in the SQL cmd

Comment: @Eliot Thanks for response, but my dropdownbox have fixed data fill from db, I need to change the db table below not the checkbox value, btw thank you.

Comment: ok, if possible provide the current screenshot and make a demo img which explain what change you want on it

Comment: @Eliot I made a gif, when user choose the value of dropdownbox 1,2,3 then the dataTable below will be change. https://gifmaker.me/PlayGIFAnimation.php?folder=2021063020xTuNyixcjtl0TJc5ldCmU6&file=output_jJF1mv.gif

Comment: ooh got it, so you want to use two ajax calls, one for drop down and one for table, right?

Comment: give a function name on each your drop downs, the create fucntion with the same name of thr function which you called in drop down, then add new get ajax code inside this fucntion, like ` onclick="changetable(value)"`, and '<script> function changetable(val){ ajaxcall}</script>'

Comment: @Eliot I have no ideas sir, I wrote 3 separately ajax before but the result is not I would like... I would like link 3 dropdownbox together to search, and data table return the data corresponding. I fill out dropbox data from db already.

Comment: @eliot Ya, I did the same way yesterday. It worked but not I would like. Code like that for each ajax: $("#fetchal").on('change',function(){
  var value_fetchal = $(this).val();
  $.ajax(
  {
   url:'search.php',
   type:'POST',
   data:'request_fetchal='+value_fetchal,
   beforeSend:function()
   {
    $("#table-container").html("Working on...");
   },
   success:function(data)
   {
    $("#table-container").html(data);
   },
  });
 });

Comment: $("#fetchal").on('change',function(){ 
var value_fetchal = $(this).val(); 
$.ajax( { url:'search.php', type:'POST', data:'request_fetchal:'+value_fetchal, beforeSend:function() { $("#table-container").html("Working on..."); }, success:function(data) { $("#table-container").html(data); },error: function(xhr, status, error) {
  var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
  alert(err.Message);
}, }); });

Answer (score 0):

1. Your search.php will return only the table which is prepared in the search.php
2. Your month and year list is not return by search.php ( also, it should NOT return )
3. inside success method:-

```
var len = response.length;
$("#search_MONTH").empty();
for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
    var month = response[i]['search_MONTH'];
    $("#search_MONTH").append("<option value='"+month+"'>"+month+"</option>");
}
$("#search_YEAR").empty();
for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
    var year = response[i]['search_YEAR'];
    $("#search_YEAR").append("<option value='"+year+"'>"+year+"</option>");
}
```

this code will not work, because "response" object/array its no-where available.
your success method parameter is "data".

3. If you are looking for search.php need to use month and year data to filter, then you need to pass those 2 values from data param of Ajax request, which is not happening.
4. Use separate Ajax requests for month and year filling and use the values to pass to search.php ajax request.

Comment: Thanks for response. Ya, I did the same way yesterday. It worked but not I would like. Code like that for each ajax: $("#fetchal").on('change',function(){
  var value_fetchal = $(this).val();
  $.ajax(
  {
   url:'search.php',
   type:'POST',
   data:'request_fetchal='+value_fetchal,
   beforeSend:function()
   {
    $("#table-container").html("Working on...");
   },
   success:function(data)
   {
    $("#table-container").html(data);
   },
  });
 });

Comment: So, if you want all content (html, month list, year list) from search.php only, then rewrite your php file to return JSON object.
example:
```
{
    "table": <string for your table content>,
    "monthlist": [...],
    "yearlist": [...],
}
```

and in the JS, do JSON.parse(data) and start use 3 objects.